# Number and a date range filter for datatable serverside script

Tags: javascript, php, json, datatable

I'm using Datatable (DataTables 1.10.10) and Datatable Editor. For my serverside script/table (500000 rows) I would like to have a number and a date range filter. As simple text filter is working fine. Where and how can I modify the `data.php` for the range filter to work? That's my setup:

```
<html>
     <input data-column="2" id="min" name="min" type="number" min="0" max="500000"> 
     <input data-column="2" id="max" name="max" type="number" min="0" max="500000">
</html>
```

my script:

```
 var table = $('#my-table').DataTable( {
    dom: "Blfrtip",
    ajax: {
        url: "/data.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: function (d) { 
            d.minDate = $('#min').val(); 
            d.maxDate = $('#max').val(); 
        },
    }
...
});

$('#min, #max').keyup( function() {
    table.ajax.reload();
});
```

Do I need to further define the values in .... data:

```
function (d) { d.minDate = $('#min').val(); d.maxDate = $('#max').val(); } }, 
...
```

with sth like:

```
function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
    var min = parseInt( $('#min').val(), 10 );
    var max = parseInt( $('#max').val(), 10 );
    var id = parseFloat( data[6] ) || 0; 

    if ( ( isNaN( min ) && isNaN( max ) ) ||
         ( isNaN( min ) && id <= max ) ||
         ( min <= id   && isNaN( max ) ) ||
         ( min <= id   && id <= max ) )
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, You dont!

```
function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
var min = parseInt( $('#min').val(), 10 );
var max = parseInt( $('#max').val(), 10 );
var id = parseFloat( data[6] ) || 0; 

if ( ( isNaN( min ) && isNaN( max ) ) ||
     ( isNaN( min ) && id <= max ) ||
     ( min <= id   && isNaN( max ) ) ||
     ( min <= id   && id <= max ) )
{
    return true;
}
return false;
}
```

is only for when your datatable instance works entirely on frontend.

Now that you've passed `d.minDate` & `d.maxDate` to server, try to catch them via `$_POST` array on serverside, then in your DB query(or whatever infrastructure you use to retrieve data) use sth like:

```
 $query = '... WHERE date >= minDate & date <= maxDate ...';
```

to filter data using these parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can see on:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="500000">
```

instead of :

```
<input type="text">
```

So in this case you should add validation for text input

Comment: Thanks, I adjusted it accordingly. But the filter still doesn't apply. What else do I need to do? I'm not exactly sure what I need to do with the function( settings, data, dataIndex ) from above. That's the number range example script provided for client side script (here: https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html). But how should my serverside script look like?